# C# EF6 LINQ Select multiple 2nd childs from child in include()

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-6

So I'm trying to include multiple nested properties from a child with LINQ

```
var templates = context.Templates
                        .Include(t => t.template_fields)
                        .Include(t => t.templateinstances.Select(ti => ti.templateinstance_fields))
                        .Include(t => t.templateinstances.Select(ti => ti.templateinstance_categories.Select(tic => tic.category)))
                        .ToList();
```

But when I include t.templateinstances more than once, I get a NullPointerException when the ToList() call is made.

There is no problem if t.templateinstances is only included once.

Comment: EF6.1.3 or 6.2?

Answer (score 0):

You should check possible null properties. Perhabs it should be;

```
    var templates = context.Templates
                            .Include(t => t.template_fields)
                            .Include(t => t.templateinstances.Where(ti => ti != null).Select(ti => ti.templateinstance_fields))
                            .Include(t => t.templateinstances.Where(ti => ti != null && ti.templateinstance_categories != null).Select(ti => ti.templateinstance_categories.Select(tic => tic.category)))
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For EF 6

```
using System.Data.Entity;

query.Include(x => x.Collection.Select(y => y.Property))
```

See [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1) for more examples.

Make sure to add `using System.Data.Entity;` to get the version of `Include` that takes in a lambda.

---

If you are using EF Core you can use the new method [`ThenInclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)

```
query.Include(x => x.Collection)
     .ThenInclude(x => x.Property);
```

Comment: There is no `ThenInclude` in EF6.